# Error in an inductive proof of the triangularization

Tags: linear-algebra

In the linear algebra textbook, there is a proof(?) of the triangularization in the case of $F = \mathbb C$ (that is, if $T:V \to V$ is linear or $T$ is a square matrix, if we define a linear operator $L_T v = Tv$ if $T$ is a matrix, then there is a basis of $V$ such that the matrix representation of $T$ is an upper triangular matrix) with an ERROR:

If $n=\operatorname{dim} V =1$ then it is trivial. So we assume that $n\ge 2$. Let $v_1$ be an eigenvector of $T$ with an eigenvector $\lambda$(it is possible since $F = \mathbb C$), and we can make a basis $\mathfrak B=\{v_1, \cdots, v_n\}$ which contains the vector $v_1$(Basis extension theorem.) Then the matrix representation of $T$ is 
$$[T] _\mathfrak B ^\mathfrak B = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda & * \\ \mathbf 0 & B \end{pmatrix}$$ for some (n-1) by (n-1) square matrix $B$. Consider a subspace $W = \left< v_2, \cdots , v_n \right>$ of $V$. Since the dimension of $W$ is less than the dimension of $V$, it proved by the induction. (NOT PROVED)

I think also the proof is wrong because $W$ is not $T$-invariant, but I am not sure that my thought is right. How can I make the argument (that the proof above is wrong) clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that $W$ need not be $T$-invariant, but this only says that the matrix representation of $T$ need not be block-diagonal, i.e., we might have $*\neq 0$. We have a direct sum decomposition $V = \langle v_1 \rangle \oplus W$. The matrix $B$ is precisely the representation of the endomorphism of $W$ which is given by the composition $$ W \xrightarrow{T\rvert_W} V = \langle v_1 \rangle \oplus W \to W,$$
where the second map is the projection onto the second factor. This is an endomorphism of an $n-1$-dimensional space, so we can apply induction.